# Django Admin Search via Tag

Tags: python, django, tags, django-admin, django-taggit

How do I search in **django admin-panel** using **tag**?

It will search using tag which known as *django-taggit* package.

**admin.py**

```
@staticmethod
def get_tags(obj):
       tags = []
       for tag in obj.tags.all():
           tags.append(str(tag))
       return ', '.join(tags)

 list_display = (
        'id'
        'portions',
        'get_tags',
        'created'
    )
    search_fields = ('name', get_tags, 'created', 'id')`
```

models.py

```
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

tags = TaggableManager(through=TaggedOffer, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(
        null=True,
        max_digits=10,
        decimal_places=2,
        validators=[positive_decimal]
    )
```

**Error** 
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:
Cannot resolve keyword 'get_tags' into field.

Comment: Please give more context of what you are trying to archive! What models do you have? How is the package integrated in your application. What model(s) do you want to search by tag?

Comment: Please have a look now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in admin,py
 search_fields = ('name', get_tags, 'created', 'id')`change it to 
 search_fields = ('name', 'tags__name', 'created', 'id')`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is case sensitive